# No view found for id 0x7f0a002f (id/container) for fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

In my `FragementActivity`(homescreen), I have called a `Category_fragment` and in my fragmnet a view pager is used which has `FragmentPagerAdapter`, so basically I have nested fragments, and I want to go to another fragment, also I have used `getChildFragmentManager()` in place of `getFragmentManager()`, error is basically my container/view from homescreen is unable to inflate in nested fragment... please help.

Below is my code:

---

1st fragment:

```
FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
adapter = new Category_PagerAdapter(getActivity(), manager,arrayList_category);
pager.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    try {
        if (position == Category_Screen.FIRST_PAGE)
            scale = Category_Screen.BIG_SCALE;
        else
            scale = Category_Screen.SMALL_SCALE;
            position = position % arrayList_category.size();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Carousal_First_screen.newInstance(context, position, scale,arrayList_category);
}
```

Nested fragment code:

```
iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("id", category_id);
        Fragment fragment = new Category_Map();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the layout you inflated in activity is no any view with id "container"

Comment: yes because container is my framelayout in FragmentActivity